Prop is not giving effect
This is my react component
const ButtonComponent = ({ children, onClick, disabled, className = "" }) => {
  console.log("class name is ", className);

  const buttonClassName = `
    bg-green-700 
    flex 
    hover:bg-green-500 
    transition 
    duration-300 
    ease-in-out 
    text-white 
    h-auto 
    text-base 
    p-2 
    rounded-[5px] 
    m-2 
    ${
      disabled
        ? "bg-teal-200 text-teal-800 cursor-not-allowed"
        : "cursor-pointer"
    } 
    ${className}
  `;

  return (
    <button onClick={onClick} className={buttonClassName} disabled={disabled}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default ButtonComponent;
The console.log is working properly, but in the JSX, the className prop is not giving right value.

The code is not wrong. May be, the className does not have the compatible string.

In what way is it not the right value? If const buttonClassName = \${className}`` is it empty? Please edit your question to clarify

The thing is...whatever value is passed as prop to the component it is not being added to the jsx... but console.log is working fine'

I think the problem is with tailwind css, tailwind doesn't build classes if you don't use them directly in the className property. If you are sure to use classes in your project use the safelist directive in the tailwind config file or use the full name of the classes in the conditionals.
This post talks about it
https://www.vincentschmalbach.com/tailwind-css-and-dynamic-or-conditional-class-names-in-vue/
Is for vue but explain the problem.
